# Java put different objects in the same arrayList

Tags: java, arrays

I have a Airport class where I built the airport object. Now, I am trying to put different objects in the same array but without changing the object name every single time.
The problem is that my program will only get the last object instead of getting all of them.
'''
public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ArrayList <Airport> myAl = new ArrayList();
    Airport obj = new Airport();
    int i = -1;
    obj.setValues(++i, "Wright-Patterson Air Force Base", "OH", 39.819527, -84.067406, 0);
    myAl.add(obj);
    obj.setValues(++i, "John F. Kennedy International Airport", "NY",40.641766 , -73.780968,0);
    myAl.add(obj);
    obj.setValues(++i, "Charlotte Douglas International Airport", "NC", 35.213890, -80.943054, 0);
    myAl.add(obj);
    obj.setValues(++i, "O’Hare International Airport", " IL", 41.978611, -87.904724, 0);
    myAl.add(obj);
    obj.setValues(++i, "Tucson International Airport", "AZ", 32.116112, -110.941109, 0);
    myAl.add(obj);

    Airport xx = new Airport();
    for(i =0; i<myAl.size();i++)
    {
        xx = myAl.get(i);
        System.out.print(xx.getId() +" " + xx.getFullName()+"\n");
    }


}}
```

'''
Output

```
4 Tucson International Airport AZ 
4 Tucson International Airport AZ 
4 Tucson International Airport AZ 
4 Tucson International Airport AZ 
4 Tucson International Airport AZ
```

Comment: you are not creating new object, you are updating existing object. Create new object every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new Object first

```
ArrayList <Airport> myAl = new ArrayList();
Airport obj = new Airport();
int i = -1;
obj.setValues(++i, "Wright-Patterson Air Force Base", "OH", 39.819527, -84.067406, 0);
myAl.add(obj);

obj = new Airport();
obj.setValues(++i, "John F. Kennedy International Airport", "NY",40.641766 , -73.780968,0);
myAl.add(obj);

obj = new Airport();
obj.setValues(++i, "Charlotte Douglas International Airport", "NC", 35.213890, -80.943054, 0);
myAl.add(obj);

obj = new Airport();
obj.setValues(++i, "O’Hare International Airport", " IL", 41.978611, -87.904724, 0);
myAl.add(obj);

// etc
```

Comment: Could u tell me now how to use a specific variable from a specific obj n the list????

Comment: [ArrayList ::get](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int))  Please also consider to accept and upvote my answer